# How do I filter categoryIds or categoryId with only existing in current store?

Tags: category, php, collection

we generate a list of `$categoryIds` like below. The problem is that it also returns some Ids that *do not exist* in the current store.

```
$categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();

if (!empty($categoryIds)) {
  $categoryId = current($categoryIds);
```

**Question:** Now how can I solve this with low overhead. To me it seems like there are two methods.

- Filter the complete $categoryIds collection and keep only members of current store? (something like: getting all categories from the store and sift out the ones that exisst on both stores)
- Check the single categoryId from current, and shift to the next value if it does not exist? (something like: check if it can be loaded with a store_id and if not continue)

Reference, not completely similar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505221/how-do-i-get-the-category-ids-that-a-product-is-in-with-respect-to-the-store-tha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call category collection:

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
```

then filter them by **setStoreId(Current_Store_Id)** and  **$categoryIds**

```
$filterIds=$Collection
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addIdFilter($product->getCategoryIds())
            -getAllIds(); // get ids of categories
```

### Edited code:

```
$categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();
$filterIds=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addIdFilter($categoryIds)
            -getAllIds(); 

if (!empty($filterIds)) {
```

.....

Comment: Ay ay, loading an entire collection is shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: This does work ....................

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated because unfortunately there is no relation between categories and stores, only the status is relevant. The cleanest way to achieve this, is to override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product` and change this function into:

```
public function getCategoryIds($product, $storeId = null)
{

    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->_productCategoryTable, 'category_id');

    if(!is_null($storeId) && Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {

        $categoryTable = $this->getTable('catalog_category_flat_store_'.$storeId);  
        if(!is_null($categoryTable))
           $select->join(array('cat_table' => $categoryTable), 'cat_table.entity_id = category_id AND is_active = 1', array());
    }

    $select->where('product_id = ?', (int)$product->getId());

    return $adapter->fetchCol($select);
}
```

Then you can pass the store ID as an argument to filter the selection. It's a bit less straightforward than loading an entire collection but it's much more efficient. Also it relies on Catalog Category Flat to be enabled, but this *should* be enabled on your store anyway (if it's not, I recommend you to turn it on)

Comment: Good Works @Mayer ..

Comment: Thanks! I have no means of overriding this ... and that would surpass the scope ... would there be another method to check this? Maybe using array comparison?

Comment: As Amit suggested, you could load the collection `$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId($storeId)->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')->getAllIds();` but in terms of performance, it's really not ideal

Comment: I am trying    $categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();
   $StoreCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())
    ->addAt‌​tributeToSelect('entity_id')->getAllIds();
   $categoryIds = array_intersect($categoryIds, $StoreCategories); but get an error; Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::addAt‌​tributeToSelect() ... hint?

Comment: It should work without the addAttributeToSelect. Although, I would really stress that this will have an impact on performance. Spend an extra half an hour doing your override, and save time on your page load.

Answer (score 0):

> $categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();

Ofcourse: your ASKING a product. "In witch categories are you ?"

**The awnser is accurate and exacly what your asked for**.

So you have to ask something else:
'Hey, product: can you please give me a collection from all your categories where the category is enabled for a specific store? Yes, ofcourse no problem dude...

```
<?php

include_once('../initMage.php');
initMage();

// 880 = Test product that is in category that isn't active in default store
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(880);
foreach (array('default', 'german') as $store) {
  $categoriesCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection()
                                  ->setStore($store)
                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', true);
  foreach ($categoriesCollection as $category) {
    echo $store, PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($category->getData());
    echo PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

But you can also re-write models or just adjust Magento core files. ;-)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I loop over the stores? 2 remarks: we already have the $store_id + we need the ID's: $categoriesCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection()
                                  ->setStore($store)
                                  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', true); So how would I use setStore to use as an ID? + does addAttributeToFilter work for flat tables?

Comment: Would something like this work? CategoryIds = $product->getCategoryCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', true)->getCategoryIds();

Comment: It's a TEST EXAMPLE ! Ofcourse your not looping over your stores. How else do you know the code works if your not testing it.Open file 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract' and look for **setStore** and **setStoreId**. Asking questions is good, but don't just ask: "can you please give me code i can copy past and sell to my customers...."

Comment: Thanks Roger. I will solve it myself. Don't understand your comment about "selling": what do you mean?

Comment: You don't have to solve something that is already implemented by the Magento development team. It's Magento not rocket science.